# Quiero recorer una tabla e insertar el resultado de una resta en un campo de la tabla

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

Funcion para actualizar registros:

```
  def actualizar_estudiantes(self):
    self.dias1=fecha1-fecha_actual
    query = 'SELECT * FROM escuela ORDER BY fecha1 Desc'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    #Actualizando Dias
    for row in db_rows:
        query = 'UPDATE escuela SET dias1 = ?'
        parameters = (self.dias1)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
    conexion.close()
```

Acá tengo el `run_query`:

```
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
```

Éste es el error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38- 
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index5.py", line 166, in actualizar_estudiantes
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
  File "index5.py", line 92, in run_query
    result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
 ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type
```

Me aparece este error, tampoco se si es la manera correcta, lo que 
 deseo hacer es recorrer la tabla, hacer una resta sencilla de fechas y 
 grabar el resultado en la tabla en el campo `dias1`.
 Agradezco la ayuda u orientación, empezando a programar en Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dice que no existe porque te falta un 1 en la variable.

Tú variable se llama: `wdias1`.

```
wdias1=fecha_act-fecha_asig
```

La que utilizas en la llamada se llama: `wdias`.

```
parameters = (self.wdias)
```

Comment: Gracias, hice el cambio pero me aparece otro error
'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "index5.py", line 164, in actualizar_estudiantes
    parameters = (self.wdias1)
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'wdias1''

Comment: Es como si no encontrase el atributo 'wdias1' en la tabla. ¿Existe un campo con ese nombre? Yo llamaría simplemente 'dias1' a la variable y debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

El argumento `parameters` de `sqlite3.Cursor.execute` debe ser una tupla, una lista o un diccionario:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE escuela SET dias1 = ?", (self.dias1,))

cur.execute("UPDATE escuela SET dias1 = ?", [self.dias1])

cur.execute("UPDATE escuela SET dias1=:dias", {"dias": self.dias1}
```

en tu caso, crees estar pasando una tupla, pero no es así:

```
>>> parameters = (4)
>>> type(parameters)
int
```

La expresión `(4)` solo denota un simple par de paréntesis con efecto en el orden de evaluación de la expresión, nada más. No es un literal para una, tupla. Para que lo sea debes colocar una coma :

```
>>> parameters = (4,)
>>> type(parameters)
tuple
```

En tu caso, debes hacer:

```
parameters = (self.dias1,)
```

o en todo caso:

```
parameters = tuple(self.dias1)
```